# Is there any way I can fetch number of columns having null value and a string value "null" in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, regex

I've been looking to fetch the count of columns having both `null` value and a `string` `"null"` in bigQuery table. I've tried this query but it only gives number of columns that have null value, but not which have `string` `"null"`. Here is my query:

```
SELECT col_name, COUNT(1) nulls_count
FROM `someproject.somedataset.k_test` t,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"(\w+)":null')) col_name
GROUP BY col_name
```

It is just giving me a count of columns with a `null` value. I need to count columns with both `null` values and those having `string` `"null"`. Is there any guide about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `r'"(\w+)":"?null"?')`